# c# linq add single quote before & after field values on datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

i have data table. now, i am converting/export this data table to csv.
for that my code is:

```
var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
```

Here, suppose my fields are `**Name Number Rollname RollNumber**`.
after this query  fire. it convert like: `**Name,Number,Rollname,RollNumber**`

it's work. i am getting csv file perfect. but issue this.
suppose some filed value like: `Roll,Number` ...at that time. i am getting 2 fields/cell on csv....i am thinking to add ' before & after field values.

or any another way to skip issue?

Comment: `string.Join(",", "'" + row.ItemArray + "'")`?

Comment: no it's not working...it's convert like: 'System.Object[]' instead of string.

Comment: yeah... `string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(s => "'" + s + "'"))` then?

Answer (score 4):

CSV accepts items enclosed in double-quotes. You can put double-quotes around each item by modifying your code as follows:

```
var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => string.Join(
        ","
    ,   row.ItemArray.Select(s => s.ToString().IndexOf(',') < 0 ? s : string.Format("\"{0}\"", s))));
```

The above replaces `row.ItemArray` with a `Select` that checks each item for `','`, and puts double-quotes around strings that have commas.

Comment: object does not contain defination for IndexOf ...it's asking me for this.

Comment: i made little bit change on code:  var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(s => string.Format("\"{0}\"", s))));   and it's work.thanks for effort.

Comment: From what I tested, `"\"" + somestring + "\""` is a lot faster than `string.Format("\"{0}\"", somestring)`

Comment: Note that if the field also includes a double quote, you still will end up with an invalid CSV. You want to do an s.Replace("\"", "\"\"") to take care of that situation, too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one way would be wrap the fields in quotes on use a different delimiter that is rare like `^`.

```
var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray
                                       .Select(f => string.Format("\"{0}\"", f))));
```

or

```
var valueLines = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => string.Join("^", row.ItemArray));
```

In general you should use a CSV-reader instead of reading the strings and splitting them manually. They support quoting characters and many more features. I can recommend this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, remember you can mix old school concatenation with linq:

```
    var valueLine = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     select "'" + row.Field("field name") + "'").ToList();
```